Maytag AC not responding to remote control
I have a Maytag AC installed by a previous homeowner. The unit cools well, but does not respond to the original remote. I've tried replacing the batteries on the remote, and also tried a universal IR remote that attempted to power-on the unit.
I recall having been able to power on the unit via the reomte in the past.
How do I troubleshoot this?
What are my options for enabling remote/smart control of this appliance? Is there something like a thermostat cable I could use to hard-wire a solution? My end goal is to e able to integrate this with a smart home automation system.




if you open it you will find a row of dip switches. Compare the setting on both units

Look for corroded battery contacts in the remote control. Contact can be cleaned with an emery board or sandpaper. Has the remote been under water (e.g., a flood)? If so, there might be electrolytic corrosion damage.
You can determine if it's sending out infrared (IR) light signals by pointing it at a phone or web camera -- though there are IR blocking filter in most cameras, they're still more sensitive to IR than the human eye. Look for the IR LED to flash, for a fraction of a second, when pushing buttons.
As for "universal" remotes, they may work with some appliance and not others.
